# mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Having trouble with procedural use of **mysqli**

Here's the function:

**db.php**

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "host");
define("DB_LOGIN", "login");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "myDb");

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$link) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ': ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php
function addItemToCatalog($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO catalog (var1, var2, var3, var4) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        return false;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
    return true;
}
?>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
require_once ("function.php");

$var1 = $_POST['var1']; //showing without filtering methods
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
$var3 = $_POST['var3'];
$var4 = $_POST['var4'];

if(!addItemToCatalog($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)){ 
    echo 'some error text';
}
else { 
    header("Location: success.php"); 
    exit;
}
?>
```

After using this there's

> **WARNING**: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **function.php** on line 5.

Anyone?

Comment: Probably `$link` is null in `function.php`

Comment: this question has been asked many times. Always check if the connection is made successfully before doing any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$link` is being define in db.php probably you should

```
require db.php;
```

in function.php file

Comment: it doesn't help(( 
I think it doesn't make sense, cause I don't call function in FUNCTION.PHP, just declare it and use only in PAGE.PHP, where DB.PHP is required

Comment: Hmm ok, are you able to connect fine to the DB using the credentials you are using in the code? `$link = mysqli_connect(...);`

Comment: @WilliamJanoti he's checking that `$link != null` in `db.php` just after he connects.

Answer (score 0):

The way the two files `db.php` and `function.php` are glued together I think results in `$link` being defined as a global variable - you need to use [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to access it within function:

```
function addItemToCatalog($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) {
    global $link;
    ...
}
```

or give the `$link` to the function explicitly through parameter:

```
function addItemToCatalog($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $link) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeap it works :)
But I have no idea why?
could you please gevi some link, where I can read about this? 
there's nothing helpful in php.net/mysqli

Comment: Did you read the link in my answer? It explains how variables are scoped in PHP. This has actually nothing to do with mysqli itself, the problem was that `$link` was defined as a global variable and as such wasn't visible inside your function.

Comment: Yeah, now it's clear
I decided not to use global variable and gave the `$link` through parameter.
Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

```
`enter code here`
need
   <?php
function addItemToCatalog($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO catalog (var1, var2, var3, var4, $link) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';

end
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
require_once ("function.php");

$var1 = $_POST['var1']; //showing without filtering methods
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
$var3 = $_POST['var3'];
$var4 = $_POST['var4'];

if(!addItemToCatalog($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $link)){ 
    echo 'some error text';
```

Comment: can you explain the solution?